# Elementary OS boot problem on dual boot system

Tags: boot, elementary-os

I installed Elementary OS on my laptop's SSD, now dual boot, also with an HDD. Sometimes when I turn on the laptop, the logo flashes and displays random stuff.

Screenshots are attached:  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVuEf.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peggO.jpg)

I use

- elementary OS 5.0 Juno
- Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
- GTK+ 3.22.30

and my system has
 - an Intel Dual-Core i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz with
 - its Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
 - 8.1 GB memory

What would you recommend I do next to resolve this intermittent problem?

Comment: Please turn the laptop over, and collect the model number from the serial number plate. Then, click [edit] and advise the manufacturer and that model number. Also, after it fails to boot, please reboot, and when you reboot successfully, run dmesg in a terminal, collect its output, post it to someplace on the web, and add its address to your question so we can see the log file generated by _dmesg_; also, please do the same with the contents of /var/log/boot.log. Please do not respond with a Comment; instead use edit to put that useful information in the Question.

Comment: i had got my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134720/problem-on-booting-of-linux).
After that the problem never occurred.